# Which Library I can Use for SQLite with Windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, sqlite

I want to use the SQLite with my app, but I want to use Pooling too, as My application needed that multithread db functionality, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Nuget - SQLite for Windows Phone
Nuget - sqlite-net if you want to use LINQ

It supports async operations.

[Try this link](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)

Comment: don't know, because i don't understand why someone could need more than 1 connection

Comment: I am using MVVM so and there is lots of data for syncing so I preferring this Pooling, I am going for offline app